# mkvirtualenv is slow on osx

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to create a new python virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper. But the initialisation hangs forever with this output:

```
$ mkvirtualenv test
New python executable in /Data/Envs/test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
```

And then it hangs, with no further output. 
It used to work before, but for some reason it started failing and I have no clue why. Someone got an idea on how to figure out what is going wrong?

UPDATE: After more than 10 minutes it does finish. How do I figure out why it is slow?

I have the following in my .bash_profile:

```
export WORKON_HOME=/Data/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: I too have just experienced this with `pyenv-virtualenv 1.0.0 (virtualenv 15.1.0)` and `Python 3.5.3`, though it wasn't quite 10 minutes: only 1 or 2. With Python 2.7.10 and 3.4.3 it's been very quick, no hanging.